# Call a function on Form Submit and then pass variables into the function

Tags: php, validation

I have a PHP function to strip any dodgy characters that may be used maliciously.

```
<?php
    function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 
        preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
        $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

        if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
            if($invert == FALSE) { 
                return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
            } 

            else { 
                return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
            } 
        } 

        else if($invert == FALSE) { 
            return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 

        return $text; 
    }
?>
```

I have a Sign Up form above this function and I want to pass every single form input through this function to have it stripped of all characters.

How would I do this?

Comment: What about passing the whole array and do a loop??

Answer (score 0):

```
$stripped = array();
foreach($_POST as $index => $value){
    $stripped[$index] = strip_tags_content($value);
}
```

Comment: So if I make each variable i.e. $postcode, a $_POST['postcode'], as a value in the input field, on submit. It'll pass them all through the function?

Comment: you post all the formdata to a script with the method POST. alls variables in the given script are then included in the post variable, which you loop over and convert the data.